# App Engine Start Up Errors

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine won't start due to errors. The information below is from the error log file created by the app engine. How can I fix this?

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>
>  File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7913, in __init__
>  File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7487, in _BootstrapApp
>  File "launcher\app.pyc", line 53, in OnInit
>  File "launcher\app.pyc", line 98, in _CreateModels
>  File "launcher\preferences.pyc", line 68, in __init__
>  File "launcher\preferences.pyc", line 72, in Load
>  File "ConfigParser.pyc", line 267, in read
>  File "ConfigParser.pyc", line 462, in _read
>ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
>file: C:\Users\Lennart/Google\google_appengine_launcher.ini, line: 1
>'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
>x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Were going to need more information. Can you walk us through how you got to this traceback?

Comment: Yes, i've installed python, then installed app engine, i launched it, got an pop up:
>title: Errors Occurred
>message: see the logfile: 'C\ Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log' for more details
>
>thats all i got

Comment: How did you launch it? What platform are you using? Chances are seeing  as this is an installation problem you would be safe finding a tutorial that walks you through it. Then post if you hit a mistake.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/Uphb04hV2tg/K6vL4osY_xgJ

Comment: i launched it from the screen you get after the installation, from within the map and from the shortcut on the desktop, i use windows 7, i did an tutorial, the only difference i get is that when python is installed it still aks me if it is installed during the app engine installation... might that be the problem?

Comment: I found the solution thanks to swasheck, you must delete the launcher file created in the C\users\yourusername\google

I didn't now that file did still exist, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.yaml file in the application route? That is the type of error you would get if the app file were missing