# Can not open Google App Engine after installed

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a question which is about Google App Engine, I have found an error while running that application. I have installed successfully with Phython 2.7.3. 
here is the message appear when I open it .

[image]

And here is an error message in GooglAppEngineLaucer.exe.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7913, in __init__
  File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7487, in _BootstrapApp
  File "launcher\app.pyc", line 53, in OnInit
  File "launcher\app.pyc", line 98, in _CreateModels
  File "launcher\preferences.pyc", line 68, in __init__
  File "launcher\preferences.pyc", line 72, in Load
  File "ConfigParser.pyc", line 267, in read
  File "ConfigParser.pyc", line 462, in _read
ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: C:\Users\samphors/Google\google_appengine_launcher.ini, line: 1
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I don't know how to solve this serious problem, could anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App Engine Start Up Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923155/app-engine-start-up-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when reading some preferences that are stored (in Windows) under C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Google\Preferences.ini (you may have to add quotes to get the spaces to work). It sounds like this file is bad for some reason. Note that it contains preferences for other Google apps besides appengine, so you may want to edit and try to fix it. You can find [the relevant launcher/preferences code here](https://github.com/tejasbubane/google-appengine-gui-for-linux/blob/master/launcher/preferences.py).

You could also try backing up this file, moving the original, and re-installing appengine to get a good copy. You could end up losing other preferences by doing this, so it would be better to fix the file.